# Combining 2 numbers into a uniqe number

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

I am stumped on a problem, I have a set of numbers (lets say 2 numbers) A and B and i want to combine them into a unique number C where C is not reproducible by any other set thats not identical ([2,1] and [1,2] would be considered identical)

I don't know if it's possible but i have a inkling that it should be.

Why? Its not an assignment, but I'm looking into combining several pieces of information into one unique piece (I'm planning on using it to flatten an array of data).

Example:
{
{2,1,4},
{2,2},
{1,4}
}

is to be converted into something like
{1,2,3}

Of course i could iterate the first set and see what sub arrays are identical and index them like that, but that feels heavier that i would wish for.

Comment: You could use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Given numbers $x,y$ then $2^x 3^y$ is unique, this only works for strictly positive integers. It sounds like you're using this in programming, in which case most languages have a built in hash function, and a hash set data structure, i advise you look into these

Comment: So you are saying that a prime number squared the number in the set? (i would need to order the subsets in ascending order before calculating the number). Looked into hashing, but then i was thinking of collisions, id rather not have that possibility if possible.

Comment: Henry's idea works well. If you order the numbers in descending order, the resulting number will often be smaller. E.g. 2^2x3^1<2^1x3^2. And it's easy to restore to the original set because you just count how many times you can divide by two, then by 3 and so on until you've factorised the number

Comment: How about you map each set to the product of the corresponding prime numbers? For example, $f(2,1,4) = P_2 \cdot P_1 \cdot P_4 = 3\cdot2\cdot7=42$.